# Laravel 5 - How do I handle MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, exception, laravel-5

Where can I catch a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` in Laravel 5+?

In Laravel 4 I was able to do this in `start/global.php`.

Comment: Why do you want to catch it ? If you are sending a POST request on a GET route you will get that exception

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
// Exceptions/Handler.php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;

public function render($request, \Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        // …
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: If you have a problem using `code`instanceof`code` with php 7.1 you can use `code`is_a()`code`. If someone has a explanation why I didn't get `code`true`code` with `code`instanceof`code` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

In `Laravel 5.4`, I did it like this:

**File location: app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

Add this code at the top of the file:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
```

And modify the method code as belows:

```
/**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) 
        {
            return response()->json( [
                                        'success' => 0,
                                        'message' => 'Method is not allowed for the requested route',
                                    ], 405 );
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
```

use this method it will work on any version of laravel

```
if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) 
{
    return redirect()->route('yourWishedRoute');
}
```