# MethodNotAllowedHttpException redirect to home page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

is it possible to redirect user to home page when ever MethodNotAllowedHttpException occurs in laravel 5 or which template i should modify to edit the display of MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[rfc2616 10.4.6 405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

in Laravel if you specify your `.env`

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

and create

`resources/views/errors/405.blade.php`

it will render that file each time an `405` code occurs, i don't think the redirect is possible , but you can always add some javascript into 405 error template for the user to be redirected.

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href='/'; },10000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Open your `app/Exception/Handler.php`

Here you will find a render method.

In render method add this line before your `return statement`:

```
if($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) 
return redirect('/');
```

Don't forget to import the exception first:

`use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;`

Answer (score 1):

you will need to import the correct name space first before you can successfully catch MethodNotAllowedException.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
```

source: [Laravel 5 - How do I handle MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276325/laravel-5-how-do-i-handle-methodnotallowedhttpexception)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ExceptionHandler

open app/Exception/Handler.php
change render method

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
    {
        return \Redirect::to('/');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```