# How to prevent users directly accessing routes (backend controller) in the browser?

Tags: laravel, api

My Laravel API is done, but the problem is I'm having trouble when the users directly try to access the backend controller from the route. For example, is if I have this route for registration of data.

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/register', 'Auth\Api\AuthController@register');
```

And I try to access this route through a browser using this link.

`myapi.prj/api/register`

The browser gives me the error of:

`The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` Some say I need to set up something in my Laravel project to prevent this kind of error. Since my API only performs as backend part only and there's no frontend my Laravel API should restrict this one. How can I do that?

Comment: You do not need something to prevent this kind of error. It's the user's fault. There's no harm in the user receiving an error when they access something they're not supposed to.

Comment: But is there a chance to redirect them to specific page if this happens?

Comment: Sure. You can set special handling for this exception in the error handler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276325/laravel-5-how-do-i-handle-methodnotallowedhttpexception